# Difference between BEC and Superfluidity. Why is considered superfluid helium not a BEC?

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate, bosons, superfluidity

I have not a clear idea what the difference between a BEC of weakly interacting bosons and superfluid is. My second question that could help me understand this difference is: why do alkali atoms form a BEC and helium cannot?

Answer (score 3):

Bose-Einstein condensation is a *non* interacting effect. It is driven purely by quantum statistics, not interactions. It entails the macroscopic occupation of one (usually the lowest) *single* particle state - *single* as opposed to *many-body* i.e. interacting, where the number operator counts excitations and quasiparticles and not the actual original particles.

A superfluid is just a fluid where its dispersion relation does not allow for any excitations with velocity less than a critical velocity $v_c$. So if it's moving at $v_c$, it will keep doing so because it does not have any states with lower velocity to decay into. The critical velocity depends on the interaction strength $g$, so superfluidity is an *interacting* effect.

A BEC can then be "interpreted" as a boring superfluid, one where the critical velocity is 0 since the interaction strength is 0, because of the lack of interactions.

Another interesting question is whether the "BEC" inteded as the macroscopic occupation of one single-particle state survives weak interactions, and the answer seems to be yes from experiments and from simple theoretical arguments (e.g. Leggett's 'Quantum liquids'). The presence of interactions causes a further depletion from the condensed fraction referred to as "quantum depletion" (as opposed to "thermal depletion" which is just due to not being at zero temperature).

Helium is a *strongly* interacting fluid. As such, all the BEC and weakly interacting facts do not necessarily apply. Quantum depletion will be very strong, and in fact only about 10 % of atoms are in the ground state, for superfluid Helium. Interactions, though, are what allows superfluidity. So you will have this. And also the *roton* excitation, if you know what that is.

People have [made a BEC of Helium](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.1381089), they just used a metastable state He*.